# Breakpoints cannot be set and have been disabled

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

If I add a breakpoint in a VC++ 6.0 project and then I start debugging, it displays this error message:

> One or more breakpoints cannot be set and have been disabled ,
>   Execution will stop at the beginning of the program

and it shows the disassembly window. What kind of problem is this?

How can I add a breakpoint and start the debugging?

Comment: Dumb question, but is this a debug build? With debug symbols switched on? Have you been playing with the complier settings, or are they the default?

Answer (score 1):

Check :

1. http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=326950]
2. http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-118951.html

Plus:

KB957912 - Update for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Debugging and Breakpoints
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs mainly when you have set break points in the source files other than the one from which you are starting the debugging.

Suppose you have started debugging the workspace MainModule.dsw and from this opened visual studio editor itself you have inserted breakpoints in the other cpp files, then at the very beginning of debugging you will get this error.

Instead of assembly code your editor shall show winmain method or dllmain method if you have set your source code path to vc folder of Visual studio installaiton. Then you can understand that the main logic behind the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem like this, but the code used to work fine and I even compared all the files with another instance that was working.  The problem was a dash with leading and trailing spaces in the path.  Once I removed the trailing space (e.g. " - dir" become " -dir") then it worked fine.  Although you might want to avoid dashes altogether if possible.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The first two things to check are:

- Have you compiled your C++ code with the correct debug information settings?
- Have you also told the linker to generate debugging information?

Both of these tend to be turned off when you're building a binary in the release configuration. IME, the most common reason for the above error is that someone forgot to tell the linker to emit debug information...

I've also seen this problem when a binary with corrupt debug information was linked to an executable and rendered the debug information unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have "Win32 Release" as an active configuration. Set it to "Win32 Debug", then you'll have the necessary debugging information.